# APM Mission Planner 2.0.18 Install Firmware Failure Mac OS X 10.11

Tags: ardupilot

I installed Multiple versions of `APM` (2.0.7, 2.0.17, 2.0.18) on Windows 7, Ubuntu 14.04, and OSX 10.11. I could connect to my `ArduPilot` but could not install firmware. Here's the error I would get:

```
Started downloading http://firmware.diydrones.com/Copter/stable/apm2-hexa/ArduCopter.hex
Finished downloading /var/folders/r4/s_j4c02s3wvcx6wy41__rnwh0000gp/T/APM Planner.uq1800
Opening firmware file...
Unable to open file: /var/folders/r4/s_j4c02s3wvcx6wy41__rnwh0000gp/T/APM Planner.uq1800
```

Answer (score 1):

For hours I've been dealing with this and *no one* has documented the same issue online. I tried the following with no success:

- Changed permissions of parent folder `/var/folders/r4/s_j4c02s3wvcx6wy41__rnwh0000gp/T`
- Ran APM as sudo
- Multiple versions of APM
- Multiple operating systems

I had to get a bit creative to come up with a workable solution:

## Solution

When APM tried to download the firmware, you could see the temp file until you clicked "OK" in regard to the firmware failure. What I did was copied that file and found the following html in there:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://firmware.ardupilot.org/Copter/stable/apm2-hexa/ArduCopter.hex">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at firmware.diydrones.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Obviously this is a server issue so here's what I did to get around it:

- Downloaded the file mentioned in the html (`http://firmware.ardupilot.org/Copter/stable/apm2-hexa/ArduCopter.hex`) to my desktop
- Changed the file format from `txt` to `hex`
- Set APM Planner to advanced mode via `File` > `Advanced Mode`
- In `Initial Setup` > `Install Firmware Menu` I selected `Firmware Options` > `Custom`
- Chose the hex file I had downloaded

## Violá